# how to use json array key to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, responsetext

i am try `json_encode($updateArray);`
and this is call by ajax and after ajax success
return me json string on responseText something like this type

```
{"title":"superAdmin","id":"50"}
```

now i want to use this two key
like

```
var text = title;
var id   = id;
```

who can i user this two to as diff. variable.
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You parse the `responseText` into an object graph using `JSON.parse`:

```
var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

[All modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json) have `JSON.parse` now (but not IE7 and earlier; for them, you can use a library like [the ones Crockford has on his github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).)

Once you have the object graph (which is just a single object, in your case), you can get the information:

```
var title = result.title;
var id = result.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse`:

```
var json = '{"title":"superAdmin","id":"50"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

And now, you can do:

```
var text = obj.title;
var id = obj.id;
```